# How to call GetCompany API to get LinkedIn details of other companies in offline process like scheduled job?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

We use http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/ for getting information about any company and we publish this info in our Company's Marketplace website for that Company's storefront. Our customer logs into the portal and sync company information from LinkedIn using OAUTH 2.0 flow via user's access token. So far we are good.

When customer updates the company profile, how can we get these updates reflected in our company storefront using API? In this case there is no user/browser, its offline process like scheduled job. We’re looking for a way to regularly sync their LinkedIn information with our site while the user is offline instead of a “one-time” copy. Since there is no user interaction here we cannot go for oauth flow as we don't have user's access token to call API. Is there away to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the access token and refresh token together with LinkedIn URL of the company when OAuth 2.0 flow completes. Then in scheduled job you can use access token and url to sync data. If the access token is already expired, use refresh token to get a new access token. This way you don't need to involve the user for data sync as long as he does not revoke the access from LinkedIn to your account.